# operator= in c++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trouble with inheritance of operator= in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882186/trouble-with-inheritance-of-operator-in-c)

hello everyone, let's assume I have two classes:

```
Base{}; //inside I have operator=
Derived{}; //inside I don't have operator=
```

why this one is working perfectly:

```
Derived der1, der2;
der1=der2;  //<-here I know that it actually calls my Base::operator=
```

and this one is not:

```
Derived der1;
Base bas1;
der1=bas1;  //<-here why can't call Base::operator=?
```

Comment: I just answered this very question. Possible duplicate of [Trouble with inheritance of operator= in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882186/trouble-with-inheritance-of-operator-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implicitly declared copy assignment operator looks like

```
Derived& operator=(const Derived&);
```

This implicitly declared function calls `operator=` for each base class and member subobject (this is why the `Base` class `operator=` overload is called).

`bas1` is of type `Base`, not `Derived`, and there is no implicit conversion from `Base` to `Derived`, hence it doesn't work.  You would need to declare an appropriate assignment operator in order to support assigning an object of type `Base` to an object of type `Derived` (this would be a bit unusual though).

Comment: copy c'tor, c'tor and d'tor work the same way?

Answer (score 2):

That's because

```
Derived& Derived::operator=(Derived const&);
```

*hides* the assignment

```
Base& Base::operator=(Base const&);
```

from the base class. This has something to do with name lookup and scopes. Check your favorite C++ book on *hiding*.