# Why can't the operator=() function be inherited by the derive class

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-keyword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trouble with inheritance of operator= in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882186/trouble-with-inheritance-of-operator-in-c)

I updated the code

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

class Base
{
    int num;
public:
    Base& operator=(int rhs)
    {
        this->num = rhs;
        return *this;
    }
};

class Derive : public Base
{
public:
    int deriveNum;
    using Base::operator =; // unhide the function
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Base base;
    Derive derive1, derive2;

    base = 1;  // calls Base::operator(1) and returns Base&

    derive1 = 11; // calls Base::operator(11) and returns Base&
    derive2 = 22; // calls Base::operator(22) and returns Base&

    derive1 = base;// Which function does it calls??
               // If it calls Base::operator(base) and
                   // returns a Base&, how could it be assigend to derive1?

    return a.exec();
}
```

I marked the question in the comment, please give me some more help

Comment: Posting code that produces only the error in question would help.~

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It *is* inherited by the derived class. However, the derived class has it own `operator =` (implictly declared by the compiler), which *hides* the `operator =` inherited from the parent class (search and read about "name hiding" in C++).

If you want the inherited `operator =` to become visible, you have to explicitly unhide it

```
class Derive : public Base
{
  std::string str;

public:
  using Base::operator =; // unhide
};
```

and your code will compile. (If you fix the obvious syntax errors that is. Please, post real code.)

P.S. This question is asked very often. I provided a link to a more detailed explanation as a comment to your question.

Comment: after adding "using Base::operator =;" the code still can't complie, but It can complie if I write "d.Base::operator=(10);" is it becasue the complier I use don't support this? I'm using VC6

Comment: @shengy: Firstly, did you make that using declaration *public*? Secondly, your code has other problems. When you declaring member functions of `Base` inside `Base` definition, you should not use prefix `Base::`. It is illegal. As for the entire `using` method: it should work even in VC6.

Comment: The code CAN be complied in MingW, but can't be complied in VC6. Why? btw, I made the declaration public, and I deleted the prefix Base::

Comment: I updated the question, and could you pls give me a little more help:)