# Property-like variable in C++

Tags: c++, properties

I know that the implementation of property-like objects has been discussed many times, but what I need is slightly different from the various solutions proposed.

What I want is an object that has the same semantics of a variable, but when its value is changed I want to perform some action. This means having implicit get/set methods, implemented overloading the operator = and the implicit conversion operator.

Please note that when I mean "property-like" I don't mean necessarily the semantic `object.property`, but just a way to have implicit get/set methods (as in `property-like-variable = value`). The reason is that I have some existing code that uses a variable, I want to perform some action every time the variable value changes without changing the existing code (only the declaration of the variable should change).

I have obtained this result with a minimal code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Int
{
    int _value;

public:
    // default constructor
    Int() { printf("Int: initial value undefined\n"); }

    // assignment constructor
    Int(int value) : _value(value) { printf("Int: initial value is %d\n", _value); }

    // property get
    operator const int() const { return _value; }

    // property set
    int operator=(int value)
    { 
        _value = value;
        printf("new value is %d\n", value);
        return value;
    }

    // TODO: overload other operators if needed
};
```

This is a sample usage:

```
class C
{
    Int _i;

public:
    C() : _i(2) { }

    void foo()
    {
        _i = 3;
        printf("foo(): _i = %d\n", _i);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int i;
    Int I;

    i = 1;
    I = i;
    I = I + 1;

    C c;
    c.foo();
}
```

Now some questions:

1. Has this specific need already been discussed? There's a design pattern?
2. I'm doing something bad here? (both from an implementation and design point of view)
3. There's some performance-wise disadvantage in doing this or the compiler is able to optimize it without having an overhead?
4. There's a better way to call this construct? Because this seems not strictly a "property" (this seems more similar to "boxing" a variable in a class).
5. Can this be generalized with templates? I don't see a simple way to do it, because the need to do this stuff is to perform custom stuff when getting/setting the value.

Comment: I'd call that simply "wrapper class", wrap an `int` inside a slightly different API, but maybe there's a better word for it.

Comment: I recently used a similar pattern... However, it turned out to be problematic in conjunction with C++11's `auto` because the conversion operator will not be called in this case and copying the wrapper-class may be undesired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ad **question 2**: I see two general issues with your code:

1. the first *const* qualifier in your `operator const int()` declaration is meaningless (gcc warns about it)
2. the return type of the assignment operator should be `Int&` not `int` otherwise it will have different semantics than the one of the original int and the following c++ code will not compile:

   ```
   Int i;
   (i=2)=3;
   ```

Ad **question 3**: if your set/get functions do nothing but assign/return the value they should be optimized out completely. If you call `printf()` though, you might seriously get into performance trouble ;).

Ad **question 5**: The generalization with templates seems strait forward, including customizing it for different types via template sepcialization:

```
template<typename T> class observe
{
    T _value;

public:
    // default constructor
    observe() { cout << "Int: initial value undefined" << endl; }

    // assignment constructor
    observe(const T& v) : _value(v) { cout << "initial value is " << v << endl; }

    // property get
    operator T() const { return _value; }

    // property set
    observe<T>& operator=(const T& value)
    {
        _value = value;
        cout << "new value is " << _value << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

// special behavior for the assignment of doubles
template<> observe<double>& observe<double>::operator =(const double& value)
{
    _value = value;
    cout << "new double value is " << _value << endl;
    return *this;
}

observe<double> d;
d = 1.0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful notes. About the meaningless const qualifier, I admit that the semantics of these qualifiers are always a bit obscure for my mind... why it is meaningless? I don't have a ready GCC setup and my compiler (MS VC++ 2005) doesn't report any warning. What warning exactly is reported by GCC? Thanks!!!

Comment: `warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]` Interestingly, though, it fails to produce this warning when I add the extra const to my suggested 'templated' version.

Answer (score 0):

I think to make it more like a property, the "set" code would need to be inside `class C`. How about this:

```
class C
{
public:
    class i_property_class {

...methods from your current Int class

    } i;

...rest of class C
}
```

If that works, then you might want to try a base class for `i_property_class`, and extend it, providing methods you must, and overriding as needed (note, inheriting `operator=` can be [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882186/trouble-with-inheritance-of-operator-in-c)) to get custom behavior for each separate property.

And then about your question 5, making this base class to be template should work too.

Comment: `class C` here is intended just as an example usage. In my real world scenario my property-like variable is built around an enumeration, and is used across the entire application.
About a template base class, how would I handle the "set method" (that would have a custom behavior for every implementation) without using a virtual function?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can meaningfully inherit the `operator=` (you mean that by "set method", right?), it's probably easier if you just override it in derived classes. In any case, there's no need to access properties throught the base class pointer anyway (or at least it is probably better if you decide it's not allowed), so no need for virtual methods.