# When and why are superclass operator overloads hidden in a subclass?

Tags: c++

I'm aware that if a subclass provides an operator method (let's say assignment), this hides that operator in the superclass unless you explicitly do `using superclass::operator=` but in my code, I've seen cases I need to do this even when the sub-class does *not* implement any operators at all.

Is there a concrete list of cases where operators (and other moethds if it's a general case) will be hidden and where they won't?

Comment: Hiding works the same, and systematically, for everything.  Could you please give a concrete example (in code) of what you mean?

Comment: Also: if it involves the `operator=`: _all_ classes have an `operator=`; if you don't write one, the compiler provides it.

Comment: unless, of course, it's `= delete`.

Comment: @Walter: deleted functions still participate in lookup, so it's kind of a moot point whether a deleted function is one that the class "doesn't have" or one that it "does have" but you can't actually call. As far as lookup is concerned James is right, all classes have an `operator=`.

Comment: THe question relates specifically to assignment, where I see superclass `operator=` hidden even when the subclass doesn't define an assignment operator. It seems the compiler-generated version hides the superclass so I need to do `using super::operator=` in every subclass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Related: [Trouble with inheritance of operator= in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882186/trouble-with-inheritance-of-operator-in-c).

`operator=` is the only member function (other than constructors and destructor) that's compiler-generated, and hence the only function that's hidden even when not user-declared in the derived class.

Comment: Yes, but then it will be defined in the derived class, so he won't need the `using`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: won't need the `using` in order to do what? I assumed he meant that he needed the `using` in order to unhide the base class `operator=`. Which might have overloads other than the copy/move.

Comment: @JamesKanze My guess is that they have some output in `base::operator=` that they were expecting to see.

Comment: @SteveJessop Ah, yes.  I don't know why that didn't occur to me.  (For some reason, I was concentrating on what was in the derived class.)

Comment: @sftrabbit Which they would if they didn't define any `operator=` themselves.  The compiler generated `operator=` calls the base class `operator=`.

Comment: @sftrabbit Sorry, but isn't the upshot of this discussion that the compiler-generated `derived::operator=` should hide but call `base::operator=`. So what's the point of "un-hiding", i.e. using `base::operator=` instead of `derived::operator=` ?

Comment: @Walter: Suppose there's a `base::operator=(int)`, and the derived class wants that to apply to derived classes too. There's no compiler-generated `operator=(int)`, only `operator=(const MyClass&)` and under certain conditions in C++11 `operator=(const MyClass &&)`.