# Derived class not inheriting base class assignment operator

Tags: c++

Why does the following not work:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct B {
    void operator=(int) { std::cout << "B=int\n"; }
    void foo(int) { std::cout << "foo\n"; }
};

struct D : B {
};

int main() {
    B b;
    D d;
    b=2;
    b.foo(2);
    // d=2; // <-- this does not compile
    d.foo(2);
}
```

(https://godbolt.org/z/8oKxreT1M)

It seems to me that it should call the assignment operator in the base class, just like `foo`

Comment: rather than the code that compiles fine, better post the code with the error, and include the compiler error message in the question. The error message does contain useful information, and the question is more accessible when all information is 0 clicks away

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882186/trouble-with-inheritance-of-operator-in-c

Comment: if it would work like you expect there would be lots of hard to find bugs (similar to object slicing). In general assigning a `B` is not sufficient when you want to assign a `D`

Comment: You can replace `d=2;` with `d.B::operator=(2);`, if you do not want to provide a `using B::operator=` in `D`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`D` has a default assignment operator defined. You can think of as `D` having its own `operator=` that's created by your C++ compiler waving its magic wand.

```
d=2;
```

This will attempt to invoke `D`'s assignment operator. `D` has an assignment operator, but it cannot be invoked with an `int` parameter.

The C++ compiler is not going to search D's superclasses to see if they have an `operator=` that might work. Why? Because that's what the rules of C++ say.

The following will make this clear:

```
struct D : B {
    void foo() {}
};

d.foo(2);
```

This will also fail to compile. `D::foo` does not take an `int` parameter. The fact that `B` has a `foo(int)` is now immaterial. The reason for this compilation failure will be exactly the same as the one that involves the `=` operator.

You can think of `D::operator=` as hiding `B::operator=`.

Comment: "Because that's what the rules of C++ say."  You should say whether `operator=` is special in this regard or not.

Comment: @Spencer the example that follows shows that its the same effect for a method called `foo`. I agree that the answer would better explicitly mention name lookup, but then on the other hand walking through all the details would be too much